# SQL Query for retrieving records tied to multiple instances of a string in another record

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table with the following columns...

```
ORDER_ID,
ORDER_NO, 
CODE
```

I want to retrieve all `ORDER_NO` that have more than one `CODE` with the suffix `XXX` in it.

Please note that `ORDER_NO` can repeat so an `ORDER_NO` with more than one `CODE` with `XXX` would be that many different records with the same `ORDER_NO`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
select order_no
from your_table
where code like '%XXX'
group by order_no
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Well don't I feel foolish! I was thinking this had to have nested queries and joins.  Thanks!!!